# How to make incoming text messages remind me every 2 minutes?

Tags: sms, google-pixel-4a, pixel-experience

Most notifications I get from my Android are not urgent. But Text messages (SMS) probably are.

I would like my phone to not stop notifying me about Text messages until I finally acknowledge it.

How can I do this?

I'm running the latest "Pixel Experience" mod on a Pixel 4A.

I'm willing to use any app that can do this for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Replace Your SMS Ringtone with a long one - It is a better approach than an infinity loop that may drain out the battery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an app like **Missed Notifications Reminder** ([F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.app.missednotificationsreminder/) / [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.app.missednotificationsreminder)) to achieve this, which "allows to monitor notifications from any applications which are important for You and perform sound reminder periodically" (taken from the app's description). I have not tried it myself, so no guarantees how well it works – but going by it's description it should do exactly what you want.